# In app engine, is there any way to programmatically get a list of pending tasks in a given queue?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, queue

Couldn't find a method that does that in the GAE python docs...

Answer (score 2):

No.

Because of the way `taskqueue`s work in App Engine, there is no way to do this using the built-in taskqueue library.  Unfortunately, that's just the way it is.

See the [Task Queue Python API Overview](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview.html) for details on the built-in `taskqueues`.

You can manage your queues in the [Administration Console](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/):

> - Manage task queues, allowing for pausing, purging, and deleting queues.
> - Manage individual tasks in a task queue, allowing for viewing, deleting, or running individual tasks immediately.

---

There is a library called [asynctools](http://code.google.com/p/asynctools/) that allows more programmatic access to queue status, though you will likely have to restructure your program to use it.

Comment: Asynctools doesn't provide programmatic access to task queue status - it's a library for doing API calls in parallel.